# Film and Physics

Tags: optics, waves, education

What are some good topics to research about where physics is employed in film industry? Like I can easily imagine thin film interference or diffraction etc.. but these topics seem rather broad. Could there be a more narrower aspect I can research on with regards to film?

Like diffraction grating is another aspect, but I am not entirely sure how physics is actually employed in the film or making movies or even camera lenses. I would appreciate some feedback.

Comment: Light and lenses...

Comment: Thin films are coatings that are applied to many optics to typically reduce reflection and increase transmission.  The films are deposited in vacuum chambers and their thickness is controlled precisely.  There can be 100s of layers to get the right specs.  There are many calculations involved, it is tough to find these in google but maybe you could find some examples.